# Multiple applications in the same (Host) , cause a problem in the application slow in addition to the consumption of system resources

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, web

welcome :
I use Mvc5 and I have a problem that I have more than one application on the same hosting, and when I run the applications, the RAM starts to consume high, which leads to stopping the collection of applications and stopping the space from working, when I tried an application and run it on the hosting I found that it consumes between (180 - 230) Mega, and this is a very high rate of consumption for one application only. If two applications are running at the same time, the site will not work because of the consumption of system resources for RAM. I do not know how to avoid this problem, as it must be more than one application and not only one application on the hosting

Comment: Is there a strong reason to have multiple applications running in the same host? You may be able to avoid resource bloat by containerizing your apps using docker or something similar

Comment: -As for the need for multi-applications, the business asks for it, as they want each app separate from the other, and has its own folder.... You may be able to avoid resource bloat by containerizing your apps using docker or something similar (How do I do that?(